# How is it possible to fire an event at the start of every day/hour in apache storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I want to perform certain task at the start of every day.
is there a way to fire a tuple at the start of every day ?
using tick tuples with emit-frequency = 24 hrs will force/constraint me to start the topology at the start of the day. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your own Spout and check the date in `nextTuple()` (which is called periodically) and emit a special tuple when you enter a new day.